# MaxMSP send data to Android app

Tags: android, max-msp-jitter

I am currently working on a project on MaxMSP. I would need to use MaxMSP to send data to an Android app in a mobile phone in the same room. The laptop running MaxMSP and the phone running the android app will be on the same network. What is a good way to do this?

I downloaded this app called "Max/MSP Control"(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxmspcontrol&hl=en) to understand the flow better. However for this app, the user controls the MaxMSP program with the sliders/buttons on his Android phone. I would need to do the reverse, meaning MaxMSP send data to Android app. Anyone can advice?

Answer (score 0):

could you elaborate on the part of the app?

Assuming that you are building it yourself I would simply use the udpsend object in Max to send OSC messages and use an OSC library for Android to receive the messages and do something with it.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks @Mattijs, I will look into this method. I am trying to send numbers(x-axis and y-axis) from MaxMSP to Android app. As for using the OSC library for Android, what are the recommended libraries?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't had the opportunity to play with OSC on Android myself, but doing a quick search leads to https://github.com/alistairrutherford/osc-tools

Comment: @Mattijis thanks, I will google around and check them out. Thanks for your reply.